# How to display PNG image to Image

Tags: javascript, php, html5-canvas, base64

I'm using "Canvas2Image" JavaScript tool to convert canvas drawings to PNG images.What I need now is to turn those PNG format to exact image.. how to display PNG in php after convert.my code for convert PNG..

```
onrendered: function (canvas) {
                 theCanvas = canvas;
                 var a = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas, true);
                 //Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
                 var data = new FormData();
                 data.append("_imgCalendar", a.src);
                 data.append("TXNID", '<?php echo $this->request->data['Plotting']['ID']; ?>');                 
                 var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: url,
                     contentType: false,
                     processData: false,
                     data: data,
                     success: function (data) {      
                     location.href = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('plugin'=>'hrms','controller'=>'Plottings/SaveCalendar')); ?>";
                     }
                 });
             }
```

and i am trying to convert into exact image ..

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($this->request->data['_imgCalendar']) . '" />';
```

so please suggest mi appropriate answer.

Comment: You may be looking for `toDataURL();` - `a.toDataURL();` I'd also like to say in your question you have `data:image/jpeg` when you're converting to png. with the `toDataURL` you shouldn't need that bit anyway.

Comment: how to display image by dataURL??

Comment: hello sir,Reply fast.

Comment: Sorry. I'm at work :P First lesson of programming: Google (or your preferred search engine) is your friend.